# Wp-cli from a plugin?

Tags: wp-cli

[WP-CLI](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli) is a set of command-line tools for managing WordPress installations. You can update plugins, configure multisite installs and much more, without using a web browser.

Please note that WP-CLI is not only PHP.

Is it possible to create a WprdPress plugin that would do just the same as WP-CLI, but it would work from the WordPress dashboard, and not from command line?

Is there something close to what I would like to have?

Comment: sure it's possible, but isn't the point of WP CLI that you can do things to your WordPress install from *outside* of it, things that WordPress itself can do from the inside already anyway?

Comment: yeah, sometimes you could use wp-cli syntax from WordPress when you don't have any server access. @majick.